# Unexpected Behavior from AWS CLI SecretsManager --force-delete-without-recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to delete a secret in AWS Secrets Manager.  I can use the `--secret-id` or the ARN, but either way the secret is still there in the console and later CLI calls to `--force-delete`.  The ARNs and `DeletionDate`s change, and in the console it is shown as "deleted on" this date, but the option to cancel deletion is still there, as well.  What is going on?

```
>>> aws secretsmanager delete-secret --secret-id 202112030312-dev-rds-pw --force-delete-without-recovery --region us-west-2 --profile=development
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:99999999999:secret:202112030312-dev-rds-pw-Cf10KE",
    "Name": "202112030312-dev-rds-pw",
    "DeletionDate": "2021-12-02T20:15:28.129000-07:00"
}

>>> aws secretsmanager delete-secret --secret-id 202112030312-dev-rds-pw --force-delete-without-recovery --region us-west-2 --profile=development
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:99999999999:secret:202112030312-dev-rds-pw-srMuPx",
    "Name": "202112030312-dev-rds-pw",
    "DeletionDate": "2021-12-02T20:15:40.226000-07:00"
}

>>> # NOTE THE SUFFIX ON THE ARN...
>>> aws secretsmanager delete-secret --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:99999999999:secret:202112030312-dev-rds-pw-srMuPx --force-delete-without-recovery --region us-west-2 --profile=development
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:99999999999:secret:202112030312-dev-rds-pw-oz8kB2",
    "Name": "202112030312-dev-rds-pw",
    "DeletionDate": "2021-12-02T20:17:36.631000-07:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include `--force-delete-without-recovery`, the `delete-secret` does not check if secret exists or not. It will still "work" as if the secret existed. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/delete-secret.html):

> If you use this parameter and include a previously deleted or nonexistent secret, the operation does not return the error ResourceNotFoundException in order to correctly handle retries.

Comment: The issue is that when I `terraform apply` with the same name after this deletion it cannot create a new secret with that name, and it also appears in the SecretsManager console as pending deletion

Comment: @d8aninja Not sure what terraform has to do with that. Your question is not about TF, is not tagged with TF, nor it provides any TF code. I suggest making new question specific to TF.